# htaccess 301 redirection issue

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Regarding 301 redirection, how can I redirect from one URL to another?

```
From:  http://www.xyz.com/abc.php%0D%0A
To: only url and abc.php
```

Using .htaccess it does not working.

```
Redirect 301 /abc.php%0D%0A http://www.xyz.com/abc.php
```

Please advice. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `RedirectMatch` that supports regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(abc\.php).*$ /$1
```

OR else you can use `mod_rewrite`.

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(abc\.php).*$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```